# Make page-break-inside:avoid break component if it would overflow anyways

Tags: html, css

I know the title is confusing but basically I am trying to apply styling to avoid page breaks inside my tables when we print the page. Right now that works great. If a component would get split up on a page break it just breaks before the component. However, some of the tables are larger than one page. In this case, I'd like it to not add the page break before the table because it will break anyways on the next page. Below is a diagram of what is going on. In it, the green and red rectangles are their own tables which should avoid page breaks if possible. However, if a the table is larger than a single page it shouldn't worry about avoiding page breaks because they are inevitable.

[image: page break image]

I still do want to keep page breaks for tables that can fit on a single page though, so this behavior shouldn't be affected: (again the green, red, and purple rectangles represent tables)

[image: Current wanted behavior]

This is in an Angular application and right now I'm applying the following css on print achieve the current implementation:

```
display: block !important;
page-break-inside: avoid;
```

Is there a good way I can achieve my desired behavior with just css or a combination of css and TypeScript? Thank you in advance for any advice/assistance you can offer, please let me know if I can provide any additional information that would be useful.

**Edit:**
@Love2Code I added some relevant stuff and then tried your solution. When I printed it out I got this:

[image: love2code test snippet]

```
    .parent {
        width: fit-content;
        height: fit-content;
        background: orange;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .child1 {
        background: red;
        width: 200px;
        height: 500px;
        page-break-inside: avoid;    
    }
    .child2 {
        background: blue;
        width: 100%;
        height: 3000px;
        page-break-inside: avoid;   
    }
    .child3 {
        background: green;
        width: 100%;
        height: 1500px;
        page-break-inside: avoid;   
    }

<div class = "parent">
    <div class = "child1"></div>
    <div class = "child2"></div>
    <div class = "child3"></div>
</div>
```

The blue rectangle works as I'd like it to, not breaking before. However, you can see the green rectangle, which can fit on a single page, doesn't break before. Could this be an issue with the parent of the 'parent' element?

Comment: Did you try display inline-block on the parent element?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that. For some reason it makes the page act like `page-break-inside:avoid` just isn't there at all. So things just break where ever they would normally. I know that is expected to happen with `display: flex` though.

Comment: Did my answer below solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to, I added my results to the original post. It seems to only work when the parent is `display: block`

Comment: Hope you find your answer buddy

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `display:inline-block` in order to get two elements to stay in the same container horizontally. In this example, I used a parent and two child elements to represent horizontally stacked elements. Let me know if this helps. You can fix the width and height to your need.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.parent {
  width:fit-content;
  height:fit-content;
  background:orange;
  display:inline-block;

 
}
.child1 {
  background:red;
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  
}
.child2 {
  background:blue;
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "parent">
  <div class = "child1"></div>
  <div class = "child2"></div>
</div>
```